# Adding data to SQLite through QT

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to make a registration form in Qt, I'm using SQLite database for this. When I run my program the compiler can open the database, however inserting info into this fails. I'm new to databases and will be very grateful if someone could help me to figure out what's the matter with it.

This is the part of my code about DB

```
database=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0,"Open File","","DB files (*.sqlite) ;; All files (*)");
database.setDatabaseName(path);

if(database.open())
{
    //creating a variable username
   QString username;
   //username equals to the input in the line editor
   username= ui->usersname->text();
   //creating a variable password
  QString password ;
   // password equals to the input in the line editor
   password  = ui->userspassword->text();
  //creating a variable email
 QString email;
 //email equals to the input in the line editor
 email = ui->usersemail->text();
 //creating a variable phone number
QString phoneNumber ;
//phone number equals to the input in the line editor
phoneNumber= ui->usersphonenumber->text();

//running insert Query
QSqlQuery qry;
//put the info to the table created in the database
qry.prepare("INSERT INFO Users (Name, Password, Email, Phone)"
//select the values for inserting
            "VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :phoneNumber)");

//binding values
qry.bindValue(":username", username);
qry.bindValue(":password", password);
qry.bindValue(":email", email);
qry.bindValue(":phoneNumber", phoneNumber);

//if adding info was successful
    if(qry.exec())
    {
        //display a message box
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Saved", "Your data was saved successfully, please log in");
    }
    //if adding info was not successful
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Failed", "Your data was not saved, please try again");
    }
}
else
{
    //display a warning message that the database was not connected
    QMessageBox::warning(this,"Not Connected","The database is not connected");
}
```

Comment: You may wanna use [lastError()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError) to see the error which occured.

Comment: I've just checked it, and it says: SqLite error: " Parameter count mismatch" , SqLite error code: -1

Comment: But my table in database has 4 parameters, so I don't really understand what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

C++ concatenates your query-string to:

```
INSERT INFO Users (Name, Password, Email, Phone)VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :phoneNumber)
```

The problem is that there is no space-character between "[...]Phone)" and "VALUES[...]".
This leads to the VALUES keyword cannot be parsed correctly.

To fix this, just place a space-character at the beginning of the second query-string-part like this:

```
//select the values for inserting
" VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :phoneNumber)");
```

Comment: I've added the space as you suggested, however the problem still remains the same☹️

Comment: Okay but I think it was worth a try. Also now I see that you have a typo in your query at the INSERT INTO command. In your code it's called INSERT **INFO**

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've already noticed and that was actually a mistake